# How to generate an alphanumeric incrementing id in PHP?

Tags: php

I have system in PHP in which I have to insert a Number which has to like

```
PO_ACC_00001,PO_ACC_00002,PO_ACC_00003.PO_ACC_00004 and so on
```

this will be inserted in Database for further reference also "PO and ACC" are dynamic prefix they could different as per requirement

Now my main concern is how can is increment the series 00001 and mantain the 5 digit series in the number?

Comment: Is this information stored on a MySQL database? And (if so) are you using a MyISAM or BDB table?

Comment: Yes its been stored in it and innodb is been used

Comment: Unfortunately, the composite key trick available in MyISAM or BDB won't work for InnoDB tables: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html. In that case, you probably need to split the number into two columns in the DB, one holding the prefix, the second holding the number as an autoincrement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>> $a = "PO_ACC_00001";
>> echo ++$a;
'PO_ACC_00002'
```

Comment: yes, but that would go back to "PO_ACC_00000" after reaching "PO_ACC_99999" and it also doesnt solve any concurrency issues the OP will run into when multiple request race for inserting new data at the same time.

Comment: @OMThe how should I know? It's your application :) What do you want to happen in that case? Do you actually ever expect that range to be exceeded?

Comment: @Gordon Yes It may be as its regarding insertion of every hour document

Comment: @OMThe well then clarify what you expect to happen after PO_ACC_99999. Should it be PO_ACC_100000 then? If so, do you want the padding to be 00000 or 000000? You have to be more specific how the id should be created

Answer (score 2):

You can get the number from the string with a simple regex, then you have a simple integer.

After incrementing the number, you can easily format it with something like

```
$cucc=sprintf('PO_ACC_%05d', $number);
```

Comment: But the digits has to be always 5 in count using ur sloution would yield more than 5 count for digits as it will incremented for 2 or three digits

Comment: It will always be padded with zeros to be exactly 5 digits.

Comment: What will be the case I will be available with 10000?

Comment: Yeah, 10000 is 5 digits, so it is cool, and it will stay cool even if you specify more than 5 digits. It will only add the zeros when necessary.

Comment: i tested it with code [code] $number = 01254;
  $cucc = sprintf('PO_ACC_%05d', $number);
 echo $cucc ; [/code] but it gave me result as "PO_ACC_00684" now this is not expected

Comment: It is expected. If you write 01254 in PHP, it means 1254 in octal. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper function and a bit or error checking.

```
/**
 * Takes in parameter of format PO_ACC_XXXXX (where XXXXX is a 5
 * digit integer) and increment it by one
 * @param string $po
 * @return string
 */
function increment($po)
{
    if (strlen($po) != 12 || substr($po, 0, 7) != 'PO_ACC_')
        return 'Incorrect format error: ' . $po;

    $num = substr($po, -5);

    // strip leading zero
    $num = ltrim($num,'0');

    if (!is_numeric($num))
        return 'Incorrect format error.  Last 5 digits need to be an integer: ' . $po;

    return ++$po;

}

echo increment('PO_ACC_00999');
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sprintf` is very useful in situations like this, so I'd recommend reading more about it in [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

```php
<?php 
    $num_of_ids = 10000; //Number of "ids" to generate.
    $i = 0; //Loop counter.
    $n = 0; //"id" number piece.
    $l = "PO_ACC_"; //"id" letter piece.

    while ($i <= $num_of_ids) { 
        $id = $l . sprintf("%05d", $n); //Create "id". Sprintf pads the number to make it 4 digits.
        echo $id . "<br>"; //Print out the id.
        $i++; $n++; //Letters can be incremented the same as numbers. 
    }
?>
```